# accessing an sqlite database from excel without installing a driver

Tags: excel, sqlite, installation, driver

I am trying to develop a very simple tool for people to use an sqlite database in windows from excel.
I know about the odbc driver from http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/, but the situation is that the users I want to use this cannot get admin rights, and the administrators do not understand why they want an sqlite driver...
Edit: The idea is to create an SQLite .db file, with all my data, copy it to the user's computers, and have them access it through Excel (easy to do if they have access to ODBC manager, but here they do not)
So my question is, is there an "installation-less" way of accessing an sqlite database from excel?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Depends on what you need to do with it, but if you only need to reference data, then 

`SELECT *  FROM <table_name>;` should work on your side as long as it's connected and then users can view the excel file as long as it's shared

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I did not explain well. I edited the post to do it (hopefully) clearer

Comment: I need an answer to this too. why no one responded?????